# Two computer on a same IP?

Tags: networking, client-server, localhost

I have implement a Client-Server application in java. The server can serve multiple clients, and I want to test that, but my knowledges on Networking is poor, and I need a way to test my application on my home.

I have a rooter, which are connected both of my computers. My "server" class in java uses as host the local host (127.0.0.1) on a given port.

How can I test my program if

1. The Server.java is running on the Computer A
2. Server.java is running on 127.0.0.1 on 3943 port
3. 1st Client.java is running on the Computer A
4. 1st Client.java is connected to 3943 port
5. 2nd Client.java is running on the Computer B
6. 2nd Client.java is connected to 3943 port

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When client and server, are on the same computer, what you are doing must be already working. 
To connect from a different computer, you need to find the "real" ip address of your server.

If you are on Windows, open a command shell on your computer A, and run `ipconfig`. On unix/linux/mac, run `ifconfig`. 
Look for a string, looking like an ip address, but *not* 127.0.0.1, there has to be another one if you are connected to a network, probably looks like 10.0.0. or 192.168.<0 or 1> .. 
Use this address everywhere instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: I found the IP address you are talking for and the program works. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Use unique ports for the clients and servers running on the same machine. In addition 127.0.0.1 is localhost (internal to that machine). Computer B cannot communicate with 127.0.0.1 on Computer A. Use 127.0.0.1 if all applications or on the same machine. Use the computers actual IP address if you want external machines to be able to communicate with the server.

Comment: I have to use the external IP address of the computer hosting the server or the other one?

Comment: The server will listen for client(s) on the external IP address. The client will connect to the servers external IP address. The clients IP address is not that important. It can be any IP address. However the server must have a known IP address that the client will 'connect' to.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the server bound to IP `127.0.0.1` you are not opening it to the network, only your own computer will be able to connect to it, acessing `127.0.0.1` (loopback IP address).

To open this server to the network, you must do one of the two things:

- Bind it to the IP `0.0.0.0` so it will be acessible from all networks;
- Bind it to a specific network IP address so that it will be available to that network only.

Its common practice to just bind it to `0.0.0.0`, its easier.

Once its done, you will be able to connect from other computers to the server running on computer A, however, not through IP `127.0.0.1`. Thats the loopback address and can only be used by a computer to connect to **itself**.

Computer A can use the IP `127.0.0.1` to connect to the server since the server is running on it, but other network computers will have to specify computer A's network IP address.

You can find your IP address on the network adapter details, or running the command `ipconfig /all` on a command prompt (Windows) or `ifconfig` (Linux).

Comment: I have to mention that, both computers are connected over wifi on that router. I run the 1st Client to localhost because the server is running on the same pc. I changed the host of the second client which is on the second pc (where server is NOT running there) and I get the following error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`
Note: the program complete on the localhost with success.

Answer (score 0):

A full TCP connection consists of two different endpoints.  The server side of the connection is one endpoint (it will be do a *listen* on that endpoint).  When a client creates it's side of the connection (the client socket), it will do a *connect* to the server ip:port combo and get a number assigned from a range of so-called "ephemeral" ports.

The fact that both sides of the connection have the same IP address doesn't matter - the full connection is defined by *two* distinct elements (address:port combinations).

FirstClient's connection to the server will be ServerIP:ServerPort<->Client1_IP:Client1_Port, and SecondClient's connection will be ServerIP:ServerPort<->Client2_IP:Client2_Port.  The network layer can differentiate between these (they are two different connection streams) and route traffic to the appropriate sender/receiver for that stream.